# Automatic task routing in Celery not working properly

Tags: python, celery

I have a couple of workers, listening to different routes. I import them in an application with:

```py
from SlackStore import registra, cuantos
from cuentacomandos import cuenta
```

The application is defined this way, and then the routes declared

```py
app = Celery('client', broker='amqp://')

app.conf.task_routes = {  "SlackStore.*" : { 'queue': 'rutauno' },
                          "cuentacomandos.*" : { 'queue': 'ruta33' }
}
```

The objects are called with registra.delay and so on. The names of the tasks with `celery inspect registered -A SlackStore` and in the log of the applications is like above. What am I missing here?

Comment: What are the task names you are setting on your tasks?

Comment: @2ps I'm not setting any name, they get set automatically and are exactly as indicated, SlackStore.* and cuentacomandos.*